# Auto compile *.jison file with node

Tags: node.js

I have two files with a `.jison` extention in a folder. Everytime I save I like to run the command `jison [the_file].jison`. How do I do this using node? Nodemon and gulp seem like valid solution but I have no experience with either and like to keep it simple

Comment: Try gulp and get some experience, its quite simple watching files with gulp-watch and creating tasks for watch event, i think you need 10 lines of code to watch and spawn a jison compile command. There is no too much learning curve for making this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gulp this would be pretty straightforward.  The key is to set up a `watch` that will trigger a task every time the file changes:

something like this should get you started:

```
var exec = require('gulp-exec');

gulp.task('jison', function() {
  return gulp.src(['**/*.jison'])
    .pipe(exec('jison <%= file.path %>.jison'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(['**/*.jison'], ['jison']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'jison']);
```

So, above we define a task named `jison`, watch any changes of `.jison` files, and set up the `default` task.  `gulp-exec` is brought in to run bash commands.

Comment: @acidzombie24 that's right, this code will *not* just work out-of-the-box.  It should get you started in the right directory though.

Comment: I was saving it as `.json` accidentally and edit the wrong file. It works now. You have one small error. The `.pipe` line doesnt need `.jison` at the end it will look for `.jison.jison`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [Grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt), just install npm  "grunt" "grunt-shell" "grunt-contrib-watch"
Here's a sample for your `Gruntfile.js`

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Define tasks
  grunt.initConfig({
    watch:{
      scripts:{
        files: ['<path-to>/<jison-file>.jison'],
        tasks: ['shell:jison_compile'],
        options: {
          interrupt : true
        }
      }
    },
    shell: {
      jison_compile:{
        command: 'jison <path-to>/<jison-file>.jison'
      }
    },
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['shell:jison_compile']);

};
```

Then you can use either `grunt` to run it's default task (compile jison file) or use `grunt watch` to keep it waiting for changes in the specified files